# Update formula when inserting or deleting rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet for measuring costing. All the data is stored within a table. I want to add or delete rows from the table.

Columns A, B and C have data validation lists stored on another tab. Columns D and E are the number of units and number of workers. F, G and H are total rows.  F is the unit cost without tax. That is all in a table but there is a formula out in cell M that the formula in cell F makes reference to.

The first row in the table is row 7 and the cell M formula is

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A7),ISBLANK(B7),ISBLANK(C7)),0,VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A7," ",B7," ",C7),Service_Price_List,2,FALSE))
```

I can't code but I found some code to add and delete a row.

The formulas fill down within the table so it updates the formulas to the correct dynamic formulas in columns F, G and H. The cells within the table update correctly when I add a row but the first time I add a row after performing another action, the cell in column M is added but referencing is wrong.

You might be at row 8, 12 or 13 etc. (any row) but it will put this formula in the cell

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A7),ISBLANK(B7),ISBLANK(C7)),0,VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A7," ",B7," ",C7),Service_Price_List,2,FALSE))
```

which is the formula from the first cell in the list. If I then try to add another row, (click the add row button twice), the cell will be blank.

As the insert and delete buttons work, I think I need a way to copy the formula from M7, which would be the top of the list. Or would it be better to have the formula inserted dynamically through VBA?

This is the code for my button to add a row:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("table3")
'add a row at the end of the table
tbl.ListRows.Add
End Sub
```

This is the code for my button to delete a row:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim oLst As ListObject
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=""

If ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Count > 1 Then
    For Each oLst In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
        With oLst
            If .Name = "Table3" Then
                If oLst.ListRows.Count > 1 Then
                number_of_columns = .ListColumns.Count
            oLst.ListRows(oLst.ListRows.Count).Delete
        End If
      End If
    End With
    Next
'ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=""
End If
End Sub
```